# Seeking advice on Elasticsearch index design

Tags: elasticsearch

We are building our search platform which will provide search service (indexing and searching) for multiple sites (might be 70+ sites) with multi-language (about 50 languages) support using ES 2.x.

Some basic requirements: 
  1). All sites will share some common index fields,like title, description, keywords etc., but allow site owner define their specific fields, for example price if the site is selling products.

2). We may show mixed search results from multiple sites on one search page

3). Anytime when a new site on boarded, the index of existing sites should not be impacted.

Here some some options so far we are considering.

1. Build different index for different site
   Cons:
   1) Hard to control(?) the relevance of cross sites search results, since different sites are in different index. 
   2) hard to maintain, 70+ sites will have 70+ indices, seems too many 3) Too many indices might bring performance issue
2. Build one big index shared by all sites, but different site has different type under the index. PUT /oneindex/site1/ PUT /oneindex/site2/ ...

   Cons: 
   1) Anytime when a site need update its site specific mapping, NO efficient way to only re-index docs for that type, In ES 1.x, it is possible to delete the old type and add a new type with updated mapping, but from ES 2.x, it is not able to delete the type anymore, so if one type need update the mapping, seems the only way is to re-create the whole index and re-index.

Both 1 & 2 need build language specific multi-fields for each language for a fields need language analyzer, for example, for "title" fields, we need define "title_en", "title_de", "title_fr".... etc.

None of above two options is perfect...

Does anyone has better solutions?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having 70 small indices, however, a single index with too much data in it can become a nightmare to manage. So the first question is what volume of data are we talking about here?

Comment: We don't have detailed requirement about data volume from all sites yet. But we know basic date volume of three sites each of which might have around 1 million docs.

Comment: Number of docs is not helpful. You need to know how much disk space those 1 mil docs will take. And how many nodes you'll have? What are the hardware specs for these (CPU, memory, disk type)? How many searches per second, how many indexing operations per second? What kind of queries you'll run? How many sites you'll have in the future? Do you have the liberty of adding more nodes in the future?

Comment: Thanks Andrei. Here are indices info. Disk space: around 10 GB. Node number: 6 data nodes (will scale out if necessary). Hardware spec: Azure VM with 14G memory, 8 Cores CPU and 5TB data disk (non-SSD). Searches per second: around 200. Index per second: we do incremental index, so most of the time, less than 100,000 per Day.  Site number: we expect 70+ sites in future.

Comment: Any other people has suggestion?